# Email Blade Got Undefined variable: when using Laravel queue

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I tried to queue successful email whenever someone place new order on my website. I used event and listener to accomplish this. Below is my code for sending the email on listener file:

**NewOrderListener.php**

```
 public function handle($event)
    {
        try {
            dump('new order registered (listernerrr)');
    
            $email = $event->order['email'];
            
            Mail::send('email.order_mail_customer', $event->order, function($message) use($email)
            {
                dump($email);
                $sub_data = (Lang::has(Session::get('front_lang_file').'.FRONT_ORDER_SUCCSESS')) ? trans(Session::get('front_lang_file').'.FRONT_ORDER_SUCCSESS') : trans($this->FRONT_LANGUAGE.'.FRONT_ORDER_SUCCSESS');

                dump($sub_data);

                $message->to('googleadmin@gmail.com')->subject($sub_data);
                dump('email sent');

            });

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dump($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

**email.order_mail_customer.blade.php file :**

```
<html>
    <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        @if(count($order_details) > 0)

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" style="border:1px solid #ddd;">
                    
            
            <tr>
                <td style="border-top: 5px solid #f7d501;">
                <table style="padding:10px;width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            @php $path = url('').'/public/images/noimage/default_image_logo.jpg'; @endphp
                            @if(count($logo_settings_details) > 0)
                            @php
                                foreach($logo_settings_details as $logo_set_val){ }
                            @endphp
                            @if($logo_set_val->admin_logo != '')
                                @php $filename = public_path('images/logo/').$logo_set_val->admin_logo; @endphp 
                                @if(file_exists($filename))
                                @php $path = url('').'/public/images/logo/'.$logo_set_val->admin_logo; @endphp
                                @endif
                            @endif                          
                            @endif
                            <img src="{{$path}}" alt="@lang(Session::get('front_lang_file').'.ADMIN_LOGO')" class="img-responsive logo"  width="100">
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

**Exception message:**
*Undefined variable: logo_settings_details in email.order_mail_customer.blade.php*

Above code running OK when I set queue driver=sync and without queue.

But I got undefined property/variable on order_mail_customer.blade.php when I'm using queue by setting up driver=database and implements ShouldQueue to NewOrderListener file. Hopefully someone could help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: auth is not available in queue,  You need to pass user instance to your mailable/notification class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've found the issue, this variable couldn't be call because of this variable is static variable, it get destroy before the queue got running.